# Rails inner join combined with geocoding gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

I have 2 related rails models

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rates
  geocoded_by ....
end

class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :location
end
```

I am using the geocoder gem - http://www.rubygeocoder.com

I want to find all rates with a particular `pair` attribute that are within a certain distance to the user.

In SQL, I would do an inner join on the rates

```
SELECT * FROM rates INNER JOIN locations ON rates.location_id=locations.id;
```

Then, insert a where condition to filter on the pair attribute, and then use the Geocoder's near method on the resulting table (the near method works by inserting a where condition into the query which calculates the distance using latitude and longitude attributes on location) to only select the rows within the right distance

How can I do this in rails? I tried

```
rates = Rate.joins(:locations)
```

I get

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'locations' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

I want to do this

```
rates = Rate.joins(:locations).near(my_latitude, my_longitude, distance).where(:rates => {:pair => 'xxxx'})
```

but I get

```
undefined method `near' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xa075ff8>
```

Comment: Since it's a belongs_to, i think `:locations` needs to be singular. Not sure if this will work, but you might need to just re-order your method calls a bit. Depends on how the gem works with ARel. `Rate.near(my_latitude, my_longitude, distance).join(:location).where(:rates => {:pair => 'xxxx'})`

Answer (score 11):

```
near = Location.near(location, radius)
Rate.includes(:location).references(:location).merge(near)
```

This is chainable with other Location or Rate scopes

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old one, but still not answered, nowhere :)

I ran into the same Problem, then stumbled upon a little info [deep down in the geocoder documentation](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#known-issue), where it said that in order to make an outer join work (which in rails is done with includes), you should use join in combination with :select and that did it for me (I needed to find all the products from users within a certain location).

So just from the top of my head, this might work in your case:

```
rates = Location.near(my_latitude, my_longitude, distance, :select => "rates.*").joins(:locations).where(:rates => {:pair => 'xxxx'})
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This solution creates a lot of problems: you cannot use scopes, partials don't work because Rails trys to render Location instead of rates, etc.